# Отследить появление кнопки в DOM и выполнить на ней действие?

Tags: javascript, dom

На сайте появляется кнопка, которая по нажатию на нее исчезает.
Кнопку я ищу и нажимаю на нее скриптом:

```
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    elems[0].click();
```

Но скрипт приходится активировать вручную.

Как автоматически отследить через observe появление кнопки с классом button в DOM и при появлении данного класса выполнить мой код с кликом на нее?
P.S. Код желательно на чистом js. Спасибо!

Comment: Во-первых, почитать про [MutationObserver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer). Во-вторых, это ваш сайт или чужой? Если чужой, то не грузите ли Вы его в `<iframe>`? Или вы используете *userScript*-ы? Уточните в вопросе.

Comment: Это чужой сайт и там выскакивает всплывашка с крестиком button с классом buttom